# Python file is now completely empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

So I've been working on a python file in Idle 3.5 (64 bit) and this morning I went to open it and it is completely blank in Idle. When I opened it with Notepad++ it was just a long line that said NULL. In the directory it still says the file is 19KB. What gives? I have a backed up version but I'm not sure why this happened.

Comment: Without knowing what you were doing theres not much to say. It may well just be a hard drive issue

Comment: If on Windows, I would try to run chkdsk.  You may need to search for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably corrupted, which is why it appears to have lost its contents.